# How to filter out certain rows in MySQL dynamically to query against them?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, indexing, query-performance

I have a PHP - MySQL set up . I have a table  `devicevalue`   structure of it is like this

```
devId | vals | date          | time
xysz  | 23   | 2020.02.17    | 22.06
abcs  | 44   | 2020.02.31    | 22.07
```

The **vals** columns hold temperature values .
any user loggin in on my webapp have access to only certain devices.

Here are steps

1. On my website "a user" selects **from** and **to** dates for which he wants to see data & submit it
2. Then these dates are passed  a page "getrecords.php " ,where there are lot select queries ( and many are in loop )  to fetch filtered data  in required format

The problem is that this table holds almost 2-3 Million records .  and  in every where clause I have to add **to** and **from** conditions. this causes to search in entire table .

My question is there any way that I can get temporary table at **step 1** which will have only certain rows based on  given two dates and then all my queries on other page  will be against that temporary table ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I should have asked you to [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-performance/info), before I tried to answer you.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: If your `date` column is a text string, you *must* convert it to a column of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`, or you will *never* get good performance from this table. A vast amount of optimization code is in the MySQL server to make handling of time/date data types efficient. If you store dates or times as strings, you defeat all that optimization code.

Then, put an index on your `date` column like this.

```
CREATE INDEX date_from_to ON devicevalue (`date`, devId, vals, `time` );
```

It's called a *covering index* because the entire query can be satisfied using it only.

Then, in your queries use

```
   WHERE date >= <<<fromdate>>> 
     AND date <  <<<todate>> + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Doing this indexing correctly gets rid of the need to create temp tables.

If your query has  something like `WHERE devId = <<>> in it, you need this index instead (or in addition).

```
CREATE INDEX date_id_from_to ON devicevalue (devId, `date`, vals, `time` );
```

If you get a chance to change this table's layout, combine the `date` and `time` columns into a single column with TIMESTAMP data type.  The WHERE clauses I showed you above will still work correctly if you do that. And everything will be just as fast.

SQL is made to solve your kind of problem simply and fast. With a good data choices and proper indexing, a few million records is a modestly-sized table.

Comment: currently my date and time is in string format .If i change its type to timestamp can i expect performance improvement in fetching time ?

Comment: **YES** Don't use string format for date / time stamp fields. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks man. What according to you would be more suitable type  DATETIME or TIMESTAMP ? Most of queries (In PHP )require me to fetch records which are 5 min or 10 minutes apart.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  No.  Don't design temp tables that need to live between sessions.

Longer answer:

Build into your app that the date range will be passed from one page to the next, then use those as initial values in the `<form>  <input type=text...>`

Then make sure you have a good composite index for the *likely* queries.  But, to do that, you must get a feel for what might be requested.  You will probably need  a small number of multi-column indexes.

You can probably build a `SELECT` from the form entries.  I rarely need to use more than one query, but it is mostly "constructed" on the fly based on the form.

It is *rarely* a good idea to have separate columns for `date` and `time`.  It makes it very difficult, for example, to say noon one day to noon the next day.  Combine into a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

O.Jones has said a lot of things that I would normally add here.